# Tailwindcss colours won't load from a variable value in next

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make a card component in Next.js, and it will have a few different colours. I want to be able to use all Tailwind colours, but they aren't being picked up when I try to load them.

Card.tsx:

```
interface Props {
  // Supported colours go here - can be edited fairly easily
  bgColor: "green" | "orange" | "yellow" | "blue" | "pink" | "purple" | "red";
  title: string;
  content: string;
  symbol?: JSX.Element;
}

const Card = ({ bgColor, symbol, title, content }: Props): JSX.Element => {
  let background: string;
  let border: string;

  // A switch is used because oherwise Tailwind just doesn't work
  switch (bgColor) {
    case "green":
      background = "bg-green-300 text-green-900";
      border = "border-green-400";
      break;

    case "pink":
      background = "bg-pink-300 border-pink-400 text-pink-900";
      border = "border-pink-400";
      break;

    case "blue":
      background = "bg-blue-300 border-blue-400 text-blue-900";
      border = "border-blue-400";
      break;

    case "orange":
      background = "bg-orange-300 border-orange-400 text-orange-900";
      border = "border-orange-400";
      break;

    case "purple":
      background = "bg-purple-300 border-purple-400 text-purple-900";
      border = "border-purple-400";
      break;

    case "yellow":
      background = "bg-yellow-300 border-yellow-400 text-yellow-900";
      border = "border-yellow-400";
      break;

    case "red":
      background = "bg-red-300 border-red-400 text-red-900";
      border = "border-red-400";
      break;

    default:
      background = "bg-white border-black";
      border = "border-white";
  }

  return (
    <div
      className={
        "w-72 h-72 mb-3 p-8 border-2 rounded-md font-poppins " +
        background +
        " " +
        border
      }
    >
      <span className="text-5xl font-karla">{symbol}</span>
      <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mt-4">{title}</h1>
      <p className="text-xl font-medium">{content}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

What I want to do:

```
interface Props {
  bgColor: string;
  title: string;
  content: string;
  symbol?: JSX.Element;
}

const Card = ({ bgColor, symbol, title, content }: Props): JSX.Element => {
  const background = "bg-" + bgColor + "-300";
  const border = "border-" + bgColor + "-400";
  const text = "text-" + bgColor + "-900";

  return (
    <div
      className={
        `w-72 h-72 mb-3 p-8 border-2 rounded-md font-poppins ${background} ${border} ${text}`
      }
    >
      <span className="text-5xl font-karla">{symbol}</span>
      <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mt-4">{title}</h1>
      <p className="text-xl font-medium">{content}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Here is the page's code:

```
import type { NextPage } from "next";
import { BiBookBookmark } from "react-icons/bi";
import Card from "../components/Card";

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <main className="flex p-3 justify-around">
      <Card
        symbol={<BiBookBookmark />}
        bgColor="yellow"
        title="Services"
        content="We offer 4 different options for your child to choose from."
      />
       <Card
        symbol={<BiBookBookmark />}
        bgColor="green"
        title="Services"
        content="We offer 4 different options for your child to choose from."
      />
       <Card
        symbol={<BiBookBookmark />}
        bgColor="red"
        title="Services"
        content="We offer 4 different options for your child to choose from."
      />
    </main>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Does anyone know how to get Tailwind to load colours conditionally, or would I have to stop using PostCSS or something?

Comment: can you use template literals instead of string concatenation. I think string concatenation is not working with tailwind JIT engine

Answer (score 0):

this is very weird. I have tested your exact code and it worked for me.
([CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwindcss-colours-wont-load-from-a-variable-value-in-next-1r75ul?file=/src/App.js))